# How to execute a shell command securely as a web service

Tags: java, security, shell, rest

SO I have a security dilemma.

Basically what I am doing is providing a web based translation service for a "Thousands of Problems for Theorem Provers" application.  I take a document written in [PSOA RuleML](http://ruleml.org/#PSOA) language and translate it into [TPTP-FOF](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/TPTP/SyntaxBNF.html).

To demonstrate this translation I want to provide two RESTful web services.  One to translate the PSOA RuleML and another to provide reasoning ([initial report](http://code.google.com/p/psoa2tptp/downloads/list)).

The first service uses Java/ANTLR3/RestEasy and the second service uses Java/ApacheCommonsExec to test the generated TPTP Strings returned from the first service against the theorem prover.

Does Apache Commons Exec provide sufficient security to do this?  I realize there are other obvious solutions e.g. compose the services, to ensure that only TPTP FOF sentences are tested.  But I would like to expose this theorem prover itself as a web service if possible any ideas SO.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not take security advices from anyone on the internet, myself included.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, I will keep this in mind.  However I am still curious as to what solutions people have to contribute here.

Comment: Please narrow this question down a bit, it is far too broad to be a good fit for the Q&A format of SO.

Answer (score 3):

I've used ApacheCommonsExec, but not for a web application. It was 'secure enough' for my needs.

The safest option is to never pass any String arguments directly from the web to the exec process. If you could use final constants or enums, your security is greatly increased.

Bar that, you'll need to carefully sanitize and escape any command literals being passed. Without knowing the exact system you're on (Windows/Linux/etc) this will change per platform. My advice is to seek out a library that does this for you.

Finally, run with a java security manager turned on. This is likely to break ApacheCommonsExec, but you should be able to work through the problems.

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer but some point of thought.  Mostly this boils down to validating every single item of user input.  I would recommend you only accept simple input like an integer (which can easily be validated and bounds checked or mapped to an enum) that identifies some function you'd like to perform (kind of like a stored procedure).  Another issue to consider is how to stop or kill the shell script when things go wrong (think timeouts).  You also want to think about what user account owns and runs your shell script.  Mostly you just need to validate the hell out of the user input, don't trust anything.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the web app container (Tomcat) is not running as root. If possible you can maybe also run it in a chroot environment.

If you must pass text to the command you're executing try to write the text to a file and make that program read the text from the file instead of trying to pass it as arguments.

Security is all about layers. There's no single thing you can do that makes something 'secure' but if you add enough layers then it becomes secure enough.

Also try asking your question on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/) for more specialized input.